# Returns availability for a given times/dates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I have been struggling with a function that returns `true` or `false` if the DateTime the user requests overlaps with any of DateTime already in MYSQL database.

The situation is that users can submit car rental requests via iOS app and it comes in DateTime format `2014-04-02 08:49:43`. I'm using Laravel as an API to manage backend. The table for `Reservation` is:

```
Schema::table('reservations', function($table)
{
    $table->dateTime('from_date')->nullable();
    $table->dateTime('to_date')->nullable();
});
```

So I tried many methods but reserving date and time without overlapping have been a pain for the past 2 days. The closest thing I got to, is this function and I think (hopefully) this function is right but something is missing.

```
 public function isSlotAvailable(Request $request) {
    $appointments = Reservation::all();
    $from = $request->from;
    $to = $request->to;

    foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {
        $eventStart = Carbon::instance(
            new DateTime($appointment['dt_start'])
        );

        $eventEnd = Carbon::instance(
            new DateTime($appointment['dt_end'])
        )->subSecond(1);

        if ($from->between($eventStart, $eventEnd) || 
            $to->between($eventStart, $eventEnd)   || 
            ($eventStart->between($from, $to) && $eventEnd->between($from, $to))) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The error I get from this function is:

> Call to a member function between() on string

I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than try to use between() you could check

```
if($from<$eventEnd && $to>$eventStart){
    return false;
}
```

This should return false for all cases except where your new event both starts and ends before the start of the existing event, or you new event both starts and ends after your existing event.

This assumes that you have already checked that `$from<$to` and `$eventStart<$eventEnd` in all cases, which I hope is the case!

Comment: That won't work, there's a reason why the between check is there. Just write down for yourself when and appointment can not be booked. You will see there are 3 situations:

(1) If the appointment starts before all others, but ends between an existing
(2) If the appointment ends after all others, but starts between an existing
(3) If the appointment starters before all others and ends after all others

It it inteferes with either one or both dates from an existing appointment, you should block te slot. Your code only takes care of (1) and (2) I think.

Comment: I've double checked this a few times - I still think I'm right.

Comment: my date and time in this format `2017-01-02 08:49:43` and the function in some cases are not accurate

Comment: Consider an existing appointment from 4:00 till 8:00. There are three possible non-allowable cases
1) start before, end during slot (say 1:00-6:00) 6>4 && 1<8 - yep
2) start before, end after slot (eg 5:00-7:00) 7>4 && 5<8 - yep
3) start during, end after slot (6:00-10:00) 10>4 && 6<8 - yep

and two allowable cases
4) start before, end before (1:00-2:00) 2>4 && 1<8 - not true, first part fails
5) start after, end after (9:00-10:00) 10>4 && 9<8 - not true, second part fails

Comment: sorry, was typing second part of reply while you were typing. By function not accurate do you mean date comparison sometimes doesn't accurately say which is first?

Comment: I'm storing the date and time as one entity in this format `2017-01-02 08:49:43`. Say I have a saved reservation in my database from `2017-01-05 01:00:00` to `2017-01-10 09:00:00` and a user wants to make a new reservation from `2017-01-04 06:00:00` to `2017-01-08 08:00:00` your function returns true. Another user makes a new reservation from `2017-01-03 06:00:00` to `2017-01-09 08:00:00` your function returns false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132200/discussion-between-leo0019-and-emma-baillie).

Comment: @leo0019 You are mistaken. Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends and ends after Event B starts. I find a simple diagram illustrates this point very effectively - but you can draw it for yourself.

Comment: hello  @Strawberry thanks for your comment. I don't think @ Emma Baillie's answer is wrong, I just tested it and showed her the output. By the way, take time into consideration that's what I said `between` works more effectively. Do you know how to convert the date ` $eventStart` and `$eventEnd`  to date ? My original function throws an error that between can't take string and I'm trying to solve the original question. Thanks as always :)